# Header order of execution / evaluation

Tags: php

When you push submit it would seem like it should evaluate the header in foo() before the next one, but the next one gets executed first?

```
<?php

    function foo(){
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?message=XYZ");
    }

    if($_POST['action'] == 'gogogo'){
        foo();
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?message=ABC");
    }

    echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='gogogo' />";
    echo "<input type='submit' />";
    echo "</form>";

    echo "Contents of \$_GET['message']: ";
    if(isset($_GET['message'])) {
        echo $_GET['message'];
    } else {
        echo "Empty";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Don't use "solved" subject tags here, mark an answer as accepted instead. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does evaluate the XYZ first, then moves on to the next line in the script which overwrites it with the ABC header.

use exit after setting the header to terminate script execution

**EDIT**

header() does not automatically do the redirect for you, because you may want to send several different headers. It simply queues a series of response headers, ready for when your script does output its response. Using exit will trigger the actual sending of the response headers

Comment: I didn't realize when it actually evaluates the header() calls, but am reading up on PHP's website now, since you both answered it at the same exact time I am going to Eeny, meeny, miny, moe

Answer (score 3):

Your sending out the same header with 2 different values so the 2nd one overrides the first!

Either remove the `foo()` call or add an `exit()` statement in the function.